# how to resolve this backend error when using plpython in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpython

I'm using postgres 14 for creating this function in Datagrip:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pymax (x integer, y integer) RETURNS integer
    AS $$
        if x>y:
            return x
    $$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

The user I use is a superuser.
I get the following error when I execute this. How do I resolve this? I've tried increasing the connection timeout in the settings which did not help. Any suggestions here?

In datagrip, the error looks like this.

[image]

I tried to replicate this in pgadmin4, the error looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This needs more information 1) Postgres version? 2) Where was Postgres installed from? 3) What does the Postgres log show? Add information as update to question. The `CREATE FUNCTION ...` works for me, so I suspect it is a client issue on your end. Try using `psql` to create the function and see what happens.

Comment: If you are using DataGrip why are you showing an error from pgAdmin4. You have not answered all the questions nor have you indicated what happens when you use `psql`. Additional question: What OS and version?

Comment: PostgreSQL crashed. Try and get a stack trace. On top of the above questions, it would be interesting to know what Python version you are using and how you installed PL/Python.